# How should the green and bare wires be used when installing a new light fixture?

Tags: wiring

I understand the connecting white and black wires. What do I do with a green grounding wire and copper grounding wire that is attached to the light fixture?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box please?

Comment: I've attempted to revise your title into a coherent question, but I'm not sure I have it right. Feel free to revise further if I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

So you are removing a light and putting an outlet in?

Simply connect the ground to the ground screw on the plug. It is no different than how you connect the black or white wires.

If you are confused because there are two grounding wires but only one screw, then either use a [grounding wire nut](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Ideal-Greenie-Grounding-Wire-Connectors-92-Green-100-per-Pack-30-192P/202894282) or twist the grounds together in such a way that you have one sticking out further then the other. Then you just put the tag end on the grounding screw.

Comment: And make sure it's gfci protected. either the outlet itself being a gfci one or having the circuit protected upstream.

Comment: Any kind of wire nut will do.  The feature of a grounding wire nut is that you can extend one of the ground wires by 8" or so, have it come *through* the ground nut, and on to a ground screw of a device or the box.  One less ground wire, at the cost of 8" of Romex.   If you're not doing that, green wirenuts don't help and can hurt, due to being a larger size than works best.